# 502 Bad Gateway nginx как решить доступ есть

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, сервер, mongodb

Я открыл конфигурационный файл

```
sudo vi /etc/mongodb.conf
```

И закомментировал IP и порт

```
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
#port = 27017
```

После перегрузил `mongodb`

```
sudo service mongodb restart
sudo service mongod restart
```

После этих действий я не могу по айпи зайти на Базу данных. Проект на php Yii но база данных работает доступ есть

Comment: Раскоментируйте обратно эти строки и перезапустите монгу. Зачем надо было комментировать?

Comment: Я и так раскоментировал сразу, но не работает. До этого была ошибка на mongo я ее исправил но по другому. А после тех действ выше не работает вообще по айпи. Я прочитал после что не надо было band_ip комментировать вообще, а теперь не могу найти как это решить

Comment: после всех действий монга вообще запущена? Как ос?

Comment: да она работает только по ip не могу достучатся

Comment: ss -atupn | grep mongo что покажет?

Comment: ss -atupn | grep mongo
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                    *:27017                 *:*      users:(("mongod",12301,11))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                    *:28017                 *:*      users:(("mongod",12301,13))
tcp    ESTAB      0      0              127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:56533  users:(("mongod",12301,14))
вот вывод

Comment: 127.0.0.01 на порту 27017 слушает. Должен подключаться. Что в логах?

Comment: cat /var/log/mongodb.log 
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.625 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9733 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb/admin 64-bit host=chocomart
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.625 [initandlisten] 
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.625 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running on a NUMA machine.

Comment: Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.625 [initandlisten] **          We suggest launching mongod like this to avoid performance problems:
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.625 [initandlisten] **              numactl --interleave=all mongod [other options]
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.625 [initandlisten] 
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.625 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.8
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.625 [initandlisten] git version: a350fc38922fbda2cec8d5dd842237b904eafc14
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49

Comment: Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] options: { auth: true, dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb/admin", fork: true, logpath: "/var/log/mongodb.log", port: 27017 }
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296

Comment: ERROR: dbpath (/var/lib/mongodb/admin) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
, terminating
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 dbexit: 
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...

Comment: Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Mon Feb 17 17:21:18.626 dbexit: really exiting now

Comment: вот полный текст к сож в один комм не вмест

Comment: Из ошибок пути /var/lib/mongodb/admin не существует. Просит либо создать либо указать правильный в --dbpath

Comment: vim /etc/mongod.conf в этом файле указан путь dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb/admin" не этот а вот dbpath=/home/db/mongodb

Comment: По изначальной инструкции еще какие-нибудь конфиги правили?

Comment: Возможно до меня кто-то что-то делал, но я не в курсе

Comment: 502 ошибка говорит что backend не отвечает по указанным в NGINX параметрам. Причем тут БД?

Comment: Нужно читать логи nginx, при чём тут БД действительно

Comment: @andreymal ну если backend без подключения к БД падает, например, то весьма себе причем .

Comment: @zalex проверку этого предположения и стоит начать с логов nginx :) Но вообще обычно бэкенды в таких случаях не падают замертво, а выдают какую-нибудь ошибку

Comment: выводит 502 ошибку когда я по ip хочу провалится в БД

Comment: @andreymal несомненно, однако мой комментарий касался исключительно того что БД может быть причем :) Однако предполагаю что не в этом случае. А комментарий `выводит 502 ошибку когда я по ip хочу провалится в БД` так вообще показывает то, что человек занимается не своим делом :)

Comment: cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
2020/02/17 07:52:59 [error] 14479#14479: *327712 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 178.62.96.199, server: pmy_new.chocomarket.kz, request: "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/wwwpool.sock:", host: "blog.karaganda.chocomart.kz", referrer: "http://blog.karaganda.chocomart.kz/wp-login.php" 2020/02/17 07:57:26 [error] 14480#14480: *328490 open() "/home/chocomart/phpmyadmin_new/upload/94/128x128/9497933482eb9b8222cf42e1b5548fb2_128x128.jpg"

Comment: failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 178.154.171.34, server: pmy_new.chocomarket.kz, request: "GET /upload/94/128x128/9497933482eb9b8222cf42e1b5548fb2_128x128.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "adminka.adminka.taldykorgan.adminka.devchocomart.kz"
2020/02/17 07:57:26 [error] 14480#14480: *328490 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 178.154.171.34, server: pmy_new.chocomarket.kz, request: "GET /upload/ 94/128x128/9497933482eb9b8222cf42e1b5548fb2_128x128.jpg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/wwwpool.sock:", host:

Comment: adminka.adminka.taldykorgan.adminka.devchocomart.kz"
2020/02/17 08:03:26 [error] 14484#14484: *329748 open() "/home/chocomart/phpmyadmin_new/upload/a3/128x128/a3fae076513df7bb1a1c4ca3416bf862_128x128.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 141.8.183.25, server: pmy_new.chocomarket.kz, request: "GET /upload/a3/128x128/a3fae076513df7bb1a1c4ca3416bf862_128x128.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "petropavlovsk.m.petropavlovsk.chocomart.kz"
2020/02/17 08:03:26 [error] 14484#14484: *329748 FastCGI sent

Comment: примерно так еще есть но не стал все так как везде одна ошибка просто домены меняются

Comment: @andreymal ТС пишет, что в базу не может по ip попасть, после всех этих манипуляций. Предполагаю, что и поэтому 502 от nginx